# Create copy of excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a copy of excel workbook and save the same with new file name.

Please provide me the code.

The below code copy the current workbook and not the different file.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Target.xlsx",       FileFormat:=51
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Target.xlsx"`

Comment: I want to create copy of another file which is neither active nor current book

Comment: Ah, that was not clear in your question. Since you are just copying a file (the fact that it is another Excel document is irrelevant) just use `FileSystemObject` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filesystemobject) to work with the file (move, create a copy, etc)